# Thumbnail Uploader

Tags: script, images

> Sparked off by https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/better-image-embeddeding-and-viewing, https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/change-the-image-upload-so-that-a-thumbnail-is-shown-and-the-full-size-image-lin
>
> Thanks to @yoda for the idea!

**Note: This isn't being actively maintained and may not work anymore**

When you upload an image using the SE uploading dialog, it gets uploaded in *exactly* the same size that the file is in. For large images, this can be a problem since they take up a lot of space and screw the alignment. The uploader doesn't allow for resizing (except by manually changing the URL to one ending in `s`, `m`, or `l`.

This script provides an improved upload dialog:

[image]

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/ThumbnailUpload/ThumbnailUpload.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).  See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble on Chrome or wish to use it on a different browser. If you use NoScript, try [this version](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/ThumbnailUpload/ThumbnailUploadNoScript.user.js)
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/ThumbnailUpload/ThumbnailUpload.user.js)

### Usage

I haven't made it hijack the image upload button yet (I may do this later, I don't want to destroy a user's image uploading capability if this has a bug). It has its own button, marked with a "T" in the editor toolbar.

The small/medium/large use Imgur's special `s/m/l` URLs (if you append `s`,`m`, or `l` to the URL, you get a resized version of the file).

Note that `medium` and `large` do not work is the width of the image is less than 640 and 32o px respectively. `small` will force the image to be a 90×90 square, downscaling/upscaling and cropping it in the process if necessary ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/108821/178438)). Use the option described immediately below if you would like to bypass these restrictions.

If you want even more control over the image size, use the height/width textboxes, which generates an `<img>` tag (allowed in MarkDown). Leaving one of the two textboxes blank will preserve aspect ratio.

Additionally, there is a very useful "link to fullsize" option at the bottom, for creation of true thumbnails.

Comment: [lunboks wrote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/108821#108821) that `l` and `m` have no effect if the image is already less than 640 and 320 pixels wide, respectively. Would it make sense to add an `l` or `m` if someone adds a custom value for width? (I'm afraid it will only complicate things; it's just that using the original image with `<img width=...>` does not lower the bandwidth for those who're not interested in the actual image. But maybe you already thought about that.)

Comment: And [lunboks wrote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/108821#108821) that the resized images are always JPEG, [which seems to be true](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F7VwY4s.png&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0). So, maybe change the extension too (just hardcode `'l.jpg'` rather than `'l.$1'`)? It works with the original extension too, but it's just not 100.00% right. ;-) (In *one* test I saw some binary PNG data, not JPEG data, but I cannot reproduce that. Things might be different if there's no need to rescale?)

Comment: @Arjan doing the custom value thing requires me knowing the image size beforehand. Which can be done (in a roundabout way), but it will make the script much slower. Yep, I'd already though about this--along with a few other things requiring the image dimensions--I've planned them for later. I'll make the `.jpg` change Monday or something. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: I wonder if you really need to know the image size? If someone enters a width less than 320, then you can use the `m` thumbnail? But even then: it may still NOT be worth the effort, as you cannot do the same when someone enters a value for the height (unless, indeed, you would know the original dimensions, and hence the aspect ratio, to do some math). Another aside: given the fixed post width of about 600 pixels on the regular Stack Exchange sites, and much less on the mobile theme, I suddenly think we all could always use the `l` image? Too bad that's making PNGs into JPEGs then.

Comment: @Arjan hmm, you wouldn't, really. Unless there's some issues with imgurs resizer for images with a very skewed aspect ratio for `m` and `l` as well (there is one for `s`, need to test the other two). And yeah, the "large" thing makes sense-- I'm not going to alias the "normal size" option with "large" (removes functionality), but I can add a note to this post. And maybe some tooltips or something. Interesting point, though--I'll try to use `l` for my images from now on :)

Comment: Be prepared for a link to [I LOVE JPEG!! JPEG! JPEG!](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/) when posting screen captures then ;-)

Comment: Hi! I've been trying to use this on my laptop running Firefox 38.0.5 (updated yesterday). The script installs, and is visible in Greasemonkey, however, it behaves exactly as it did for @sdaau. I know it's been a while. Do you have any plans for a fix? It would be a great help! (I was able to install [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/6376/stack-exchange-references) with some help from Michaelpri, so my system seems to be working.) Do you need the error text? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue sorry, busy with other things so no plans to make this work with the new uploader dialog unless I feel like it later :/

Comment: I totally respect that, and really appreciate you getting back to me so quickly!

Answer (score 4):

Does not work on Firefox with NoScript addon - even if `github.com` is explicitly allowed, and even if NoScript is set to "Allow Scripts Globally (dangerous)", one still gets in Error Console (Ctrl+Shift+J) in Firefox:

> [NoScript] Blocking nosniff Javascript served from https://raw.github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/master/StackExchange/ThumbnailUpload/ThumbnailUpload.js?rand=16 with wrong type info text/plain, inline and included by [Thumbnail Uploader](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader)

Here is the relevant post from NoScript forums:

[InformAction Forums • View topic - nosniff is blocking a script without telling me](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=8112)

> I can't think of any reason why NoScript should block scripts without indicating that it is doing so. It just leads to frustration.
>   [...]
>   Not sure it's worth the effort: careless developers like that will soon be forced adapt, since IE9 doesn't give any visual clue either of this (correct) blocking [...]

Also, cannot cheat by downloading the script locally ([SourceForge.net: MathJax: Greasemonkey script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathjax/forums/forum/948700/topic/3701296)):

> Unfortunately, GreaseMonkey will not allow you to load a local file (i.e., a file:// URL), for security reasons. (Personally, I think you should be allowed to authorize specific scripts to be loaded that way, but I didn't write GreaseMonkey, so don't get to make those choices.)

Well, that's a shame `:/` ...

---

EDIT: Many thanks for the quick update from the author (first saw the update on GitHub, then the response here `:)`); I tried the NoScript version - and indeed, now the toolbar button "T" shows - but the iframe cannot be populated:

[image: firefox-bad-iframe]

I tried to mess with the script locally, and I think the breakage got induced already at `if(iframeWin.$){ \n var script = iframeWin.document.createElement("script");` ... but cannot tell much more than that...

---

EDIT2: Disabled NoScript completely, uninstalled the NoScript version, reinstalled the regular version (with Firefox restarts inbetween) - and the behavior is the same as listed above: the toolbar button appears, but the iframe is not populated.

So the NoScript.user.js version indeed solves the NoScript problem - but it seems the empty iframe problem is due to Firefox or Greasemonkey specifics, and not due to NoScript blocking.

Comment: I added a NoScript version: https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/ThumbnailUpload/ThumbnailUploadNoScript.user.js . It _should_ work. Note that you need to allow jquery as well. Let me know what the result is :) [I strongly suspect that it may not work since the script uses iframes, which themselves load jquery]

Comment: Many thanks for the quick update, @Manishearth ! I tried the `ThumbnailUploadNoScript.user.js`, and allowed `ajax.googleapis.com` (allowed temporarily "entire page") and the results are in the post update above: toolbar button appears, but as you noted, the iframe unfortunately doesn't populate ... Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Hmm, you're right, some issue with FF/GM. I made it on Chrome, and it _used_ to work on FF. Not sure why it's no longer working, will look into it when I get the time :)