# Stack Exchange References

Tags: script, posts, markdown

## Stack Exchange References

---

### What is it?

Stack Exchange References is a userscript for easily putting in references in answers and questions.

---

### Description

- In the top bar of any answer or question on SE, a new image is added, which looks like:

  [image: partial screenshot]
- When the `[1]` icon is clicked on, or you press Ctrl+Y, you will get a reference put into your post
- You will get prompted for the reference link and name
- `<sup>[1]</sup>`, which will end up looking like <sup>[1](http://www.example.com/)</sup>, will be put into the post's textarea wherever your cursor is
- `<sup>[1: Title of Reference][1]</sup>` will be appended to the textarea, which will appear as <sup>[1: Title of Reference](http://www.example.com/)</sup>
- Under the title of the reference,   `[1]: reference link` will be put in the text area

---

### Source Code/Download

You can view that source code on [Github](https://github.com/michaelpri10/SE-References), feel free to contribute. You can download the userscript [here](https://github.com/michaelpri10/SE-References/raw/master/references.user.js). Also note that this will be updated from time to time, so you may have to reinstall.

---

### Bugs

I'm sure there are several bugs (one is that the `[1]` icon is terrible), so if you find any, please post them as an answer on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6376/stack-exchange-references) or [raise them as an issue](https://github.com/michaelpri10/SE-References/issues/new) on Github.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Turns out the question ability was already in place. Also, I've added keyboard shortcuts and rewritten the entire script in Vanilla JS.